# javascript - execution context of function

Tags: javascript

Why does z() execution context not override global x variable?

```
var x = 10;

function z(){
  var x = x = 20;
}
z();
console.log(x); // why is 10 printed? Shouldn’t it be 20.
```

var  a = b = c = 0;

It means b and c are being declared as globals, not locals as intended.

For example -

```
var y = 10;

function z(){
  var x = y = 20; // global y is overridden
}
z();
console.log(y); // value is 20
```

Going by above logic, x = x = 20 in z() means x is global which overrides the local x variable but still global value of x is 10

Comment: No, as the `x` in the function is local to the function, your log use the global, which is 10

Comment: Cause *var x* is declared first ( due to hoisting )...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript you need to learn about scopes

Comment: In the context of `var x = 10`. Here `X` is a global variable, right ?  
Now, inside your `z` function, its a `LOCAL Variable`.   

if you remove the `var` from your function. It will print 20. Because it will be refering to the global one and not the local variable.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro It's not that simple. According to the operator precedence, OP's code should actually print `20`. See Ori Drori's answer.

Comment: @Teemu I might be wrong but, even with the same name, as the OP used `var` to create a new one. Doesn't all the changes/values/actions regarding that variable take effect only inside that function ?

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro Yep, but if the `var` wasn't hoisted, the result would be `20` when logging. The execution order of `x = x = 20` is put 20 to (global)x, put 20 to (local)x, but hoisting of `var`ed variable messes up what you see. Block-scoped declaration would trigger an error when meeting a line like this.

Comment: @AlperFıratKaya It's not that simple. Read this if you really want to understand scope and hoisting(http://davidshariff.com/blog/what-is-the-execution-context-in-javascript/#first-article).

Comment: @VivekKumar Notice, that in the edited question, `var a = b = c = 0;` only `a` is declared, other variables refer to earlier declared variables or to an outer scope. If you want a single line declaration, you use comma to separate the declarees.

Comment: In `var a = b = 0;`, `b` becomes a global variable, yes. I don't see how this matters though - you have `var a = a = 0`?

Answer (score 4):

The internal `x` declaration is [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) to the top of the function, and overshadows the `x` of the external scope. Your code actually does this:

```js
var x = 10;

function z(){
  var x;
  x = x = 20;
}
z();
console.log(x); // why is 10 printed? Shouldn’t it be 20.
```

Comment: This is a special case, which might be a good addition to the accepted answer in the linked dup ..?

Comment: @Teemu - it's more related related to hoisting than scoping.

Comment: Well, it messes up the expected scoping (considering the operator precedence), if you're not aware of hoisting.